# Getting configuration values rom XML file located in the same project

Tags: c#, xml

I am making a little program to copy pictures form one location to another. The information for the pictures are stored in a database so I need connections string and also I create a txt file with the final output from the operation and I want to store these two values in a `App.Config.xml` file.

The structure of my project is very simple :

[image: Project Tree]

And the XML files itself is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\\DVSQLEXPRESS08;Initial Catalog=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <createResultFile>
    <add key="ResultFile" value="C:\Users\dv\Desktop\Leron\PictureStatus.txt"/>
  </createResultFile>
</configuration>
```

I want to use the `connectionString` and `<createResultFile>` value in my `PictureTransferTool.cs`. This is my first time working with XML file and C# (.NET in general) so I want what is the way to retrieve those config values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You config file must be like below...

**Config File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ResultFile" value="C:\Users\dv\Desktop\Leron\PictureStatus.txt"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\\DVSQLEXPRESS08;Initial Catalog=**;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;Password=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

**C# :**

You can read Connection String like below

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString;
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
```

You can read User Defined Settings like Below

```
var Resultfile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResultFile"];
Console.WriteLine(Resultfile);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Way I normally do user-defined parameters in my app.config is i put them in the `appSettings` tab.

```
<appSettings>
 <add key="myStr" value="String Value" />
```

and then you can access it with

```
string myStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myStr"];
```

Comment: I think this is what I need but this app.config - I create it by just creating new XML file. Is it created by some other way?

Comment: @Leron you can right click on your project, and click on **add new item**, and then add an **application configuration file**

Comment: @Leron mind you, if you're using the `<connectionStrings>`, in the application configuration file, than an external library has probably already created the app.config file for you.  If it hasn't then there might be an issue

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, I'm using plain ADO.NET and that's all. Another project that use the Entity Framework has this `App.Config` automatically created, but I don't get it automatically here, I think it's because I use plain ADO.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
...
var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");// You should put the way to your XML
var name = doc.XPathSelectElements("/configuration/connectionStrings/add").Value;
var name = doc.XPathSelectElements("/configuration/createResultFile/add").Value;
```